# RoR duplication fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When an incorrect mandatory fields, the page reloads and you receive an incorrect entry fields and all fields in the form company_form duplicated.

User model(user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  has_many :companies, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  def role?(role_name)
    return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role_name)
  end
  def with_company
    self.companies.build
    self
  end
end
```

Company model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

views/devise/registration/new.html.haml:

```
= form_for(resource.with_company, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
...
  = f.fields_for :companies do |company_form|
  ...
...
```

Comment: And the problem is? And the rest of the code is?

Comment: problem probably in with_company. When the page is reloaded created another company, and it is necessary to record only one company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked! change def with_company on

```
  def with_company
    if self.companies.empty?
      self.companies.build
    end
    self
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `with_company` method uses `build` to create the new `Company` object. `build` will automatically create the new object and save it to the database. So every time that form gets rendered, you'll add another `Company` to that `User`. Just hit reload on the page a few times and you should see what I mean.

I think the fix will be to use `create` instead of `build` in that method; this creates a new object but doesn't save it to the database.

More likely, though, you should be doing this in the controller that renders the view, rather than in the view itself. Devise doesn't always make this straightforward, but you should be able to create a new controller that inherits from the Devise controller and adds what you need. I do something similar in my current project [here](https://github.com/myfairelection/myfairelection/blob/master/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb).

Comment: create not working, error "You cannot call create unless the parent is saved".

Comment: not terrible, I have found the solution to my problem, thanks anyway